# Java 8 stream list collector memory allocation speed vs loop with preallocation

Tags: java, memory, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering how Java 8 streams handle memory allocation if the terminal operation is a list collector.

Consider for example

```
List<Integer> result = myList.stream().map(doWhatever).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

vs

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(myList.size());
for(String s : myList) {
  result.add(doWhatever.apply(s));
}
```

In case of using a stream, it is unknown how large the list will grow, which means there must be some kind of reallocation. Is this assumption true?

Is the type of the resulting list some kind of linked list and gives therefore slower access to elements than the ArrayList?

Should I not use streams with list collectors if I know the size of the resulting list from the beginning on?

Comment: `Collectors.toList()` uses an `ArrayList`. Reallocation happens in exactly the same way as any other `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Behind the scenes [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) will allow to collect the resulting elements of your `Stream` into an `ArrayList` created with the default constructor so with a default capacity of `10` so indeed a reallocation will be required in case the size exceeds `10`.

If you want to use a different `List`'s implementation, use [`toCollection(Supplier<C> collectionFactory)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-) which is a more generic collector allowing to provide the factory of your target `Collection`.

For example, if you want to collect the elements into a `LinkedList` instead, you could rewrite your code as next:

```
List<Integer> result = myList.stream()
    .map(doWhatever)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Assuming that you want an `ArrayList` with a default capacity of `100`, the collector would be `Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(100))`.

Comment: You probably just used `LinkedList` as an example of how to create a collection of a specific type. But I'd caution readers not to use `LinkedList` in the hopes that it will be faster than appending to an `ArrayList`; it probably won't be. Yet another thing to benchmark....

Comment: @StuartMarks yes it is only as example, I don't know the usecase of the OP so I can't go any further

Answer (score 6):

`Collectors.toList()` does not specify *anything* about its implementation.  If you care, use `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`.

> Should I not use streams with list collectors if I know the size of the resulting list from the beginning on?

Nah, go ahead and use them.  Allocation is cheap and the cost is minimal relative to the conciseness win.  Presizing lists is generally a premature optimization.

Comment: Yes. This. +1. For concerned readers, note that adding N elements to an `ArrayList` is still O(N), even when reallocation and copying is taken into account.

Comment: @StuartMarks honestly I'm really surprised `toList()` ever got approved for `Collectors` at all.

Comment: There was a lot of demand for having it directly on Stream, as `stream.toList()`. People have complained a lot about `stream.collect(Collectors.toList())`. It would have been worse if the only way to collect to a list was `stream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))`. As you've noted, `toList()` doesn't specify that it returns an `ArrayList`, but in fact it does. I suspect that programs have grown to rely on this. There's a hope that it could return a fast append-only list like `SpinedBuffer` but that might be too much of a behavioral incompatibility.

Comment: FWIW: I think we're leaning strongly to pushing users into either `toCollection(ArrayList::new)` or `toImmutableList()`, and static importing in both cases.  (I would've also been a fan of making `toList()` contractually serializable, immutable, and random-access.)

Comment: Static import is a good style, but I tend to avoid it in example code since I can't tell how familiar readers are with the APIs. The recommendation for `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`, and the other points you mentioned, are worth a longer discussion at some point.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the source code for `Collectors.toList()`, no it doesn't pre-allocate.

```
    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
         return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new, List::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               CH_ID);
    }
```

It just creates a new `ArrayList` with the default size, which then resizes on subsequent invocations of `add`/`addAll`.

Comment: Do you expect that to stay the case forever?  Where does it say that in the method contract?

Answer (score 4):

For large parallel streams, I found that the toList() actually had serious performance issues because the accumulator lists were being repeatedly combined - which led to something more like O(N^2) than O(N).

Here's an alternative toList() Collector that holds data in a ConcurrentLinkedQueue until the finish stage - for a 400,000 element stream, the collection operation time went from 1500ms to about 30:

http://pastebin.com/Bi93uig6

Comment: Cool, that's a very nice idea!

Answer (score 3):

*Currently*, the `toList()` collector is implemented by using and returning an `ArrayList` (note that the container used during the collection doesn’t always have to match the final result’s type). The way, the collector interface is defined, the collector has no chance of pre-sizing the list.

But in principle, since the standard Stream implementation and the predefined `toList()` collector implementation are part of the same library, there could be a non-standard communication in future implementations (or alternative JREs) where the stream detects the `toList()` collector in the `collect` method and performs an optimized operation. But when the `toList()` collector is used, e.g. as downstream collector of a `groupingBy` collector, there is no predictable size anyway.

If you assume that the stream can predict its size, like in your `myList.stream().map(doWhatever)` example, the most efficient solution, given the current implementation (before Java 16), is

```
List<ElementType> result=Arrays.asList(stream.toArray(ElementType[]::new));
```

as that operation will utilize the known size, even in parallel, or *especially* when being used with a parallel stream when the sub sizes of the splitting are predictable, as no merging step is required then, i.e. all workers will write directly into the result array.

Unfortunately, if `ElementType` is not a reifiable type, you have to resort to an unchecked operation here.

If the sizes are not predictable, this solution might be still more efficient compared to the current `toList()` collector, but might loose compared to a future implementation that can use non-linear storage.

---

So the optimized variant is only relevant for a certain setup. For most scenarios, the `toList()` collector is sufficient or might be even better than any alternative, in possible future implementations.

---

Starting with Java 16, you can call [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) directly on the `Stream` and basically get what the `toArray()` based approach above does, but returning a read only `List` and not having the type safety issues when the stream element type is generic.

This method is preferable over using the `toList()` collector while the collector is still useful when composing collectors.

Answer (score 2):

> In case of using a stream, it is unknown how large the list will grow, which means there must be some kind of reallocation. Is this assumption true?

It knows the previous pipeline, its size and creates an `ArrayList<>` with the default configuration not looking at that. It doesn't matter when you're working with a dynamic well-optimized array.

> Is the type of the resulting list some kind of linked list and gives therefore slower access to elements than the ArrayList?

An `ArrayList` is used by default, but you are free to provide your own supplier and accumulator to change this behaviour:

```
stream.collect(() -> new ArrayList<>(SIZE), ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

> Should I not use streams with list collectors if I know the size of the resulting list from the beginning on?

Don't think about that. Along with concise syntax, Stream API provides a plenty of powerful things (like parallelization) that you may use.

Comment: If the stream is run in parallel, the supplier can be called as many times as the stream has been split. In that case, it's hard to know what size to use for preallocation.